# How to Change the selected value of a drop down list according to value in a text box in jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to be able to change the selected option of a drop down if a value in the drop down match what is types into a text box.

this is what i have tried and doesnt seem to be working..

```
$('#dropFinish2-box option').each(function () {
                if (this.value == $('#f2').val()) {
                    $("#dropFinish2 option:selected").text($('#f2').val());
                }
            });
```

dropFinish2 is the drop down.
f2 is the id of the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why loop through the list. Just try to set it directly. If there is no match, it will not change...

```
$("#dropFinish2").val($('#f2').val());
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/PDDDX/)

if value is all in lowercase you can do...

```
$("#dropFinish2").val($('#f2').val().toLowerCase());
```

or if value casing cannot be changed...

```
$("#f2").keyup(function(){
    var input = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $('#dropFinish2 option').each(function () {
       if(input == this.value.toLowerCase()){
          $("#dropFinish2").val(this.value);
       }
    });
});
```

[Case-insensitive working example](http://jsfiddle.net/NEBDY/)

Comment: Ahh yes that works, but if they type in something in lower case and the value is in uppercase it doest?

Comment: @Beginner: See the updates, the last one should work if you are unable to change your values

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I think this is what you are after:

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    if ($('select option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length) {
        // do something
        $('select').val($(this).val());
    }
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/HEeVa/1)

Comment: I want to select the value in the drop down if there is an option in the dropdown which is the same as the text in the text box...i dont think your if statment would do anything

Comment: yes that works but not if what they type is in lower case and the value in text box is in upper or vice versa etc

Comment: Force both strings to either lowercase or uppercase before comparing.